# Make links in included files global (laravel)

Tags: laravel

I have a header file that links to the user dashboard that displays on all pages on my site, but if I access the link from a page such as `localhost/pages/page`, I have to put `href="../dashboard"`. If I am on the root directory (such as `localhost/page`) then using `href="dashboard"` works.

Is there a simpler way than changing the directories on every single page so I can just use `href="dashboard"` on all pages?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/urls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `url()` helper method:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('/dashboard/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
```

Comment: @whenofficial welcome, everyone start from level zero as we started