# Laravel 404 page when try 'http' as a parameter

Tags: laravel

I have a weird problem with Laravel redirection to 404 page.
for example when I try this URL:

```
www.test.com/sdfghj
```

It's ok and redirects to 404 page and everything is ok, but when I try `http` or `https` as a parameter, like:

```
www.test.com/http://anything
```

the 404 page's images don't load! 
**(I didn't change any value in htaccess file)**

Thanks for any suggestion.

**Update:**

> my custom 404 page:

```
@extends('master')
@section('banner')
    @include('sections.slider')
@endsection
@section('content')
    <div class="container" id="page-404">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="center">
                <img src="images/404.png" alt="404" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row center">
            <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
               ERROR
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: what is it showing?

Comment: Joke explains the answer: "Doctor, it hurts when I do this." "Then don't do that!". I assume you want to pass a URL as a parameter. Take from other big websites and encode the URL!

Comment: @Sohel0415 my custom 404-page load, but its images don't load.

Comment: @Eмαd are the image sources referenced using absolute or relative paths?

Comment: show your custom pages blade template code

Comment: @Eмαd see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596468/make-links-in-included-files-global-laravel/49596487#49596487

Comment: Thank you guys, I found the solution. just added `/` before the image's path and the problem is gone. `src="/images/404.png"`

Answer (score 0):

First on artisan, clear your views.
Then just add "/" before the images word like this. Should work.

"/images/404.png"